# Слайдер поздно загружается

Tags: javascript, html

Есть такой кусок кода, он отрабатывает, как надо, но есть одна проблема. Скрипт отрабатывает с задержкой( сайт большой и не оптимизированный ). Слайдер появляется на долю секунды в разобранном виде, т.е. Картинки показываются одна под другой. (5 картинок). Через секунду все работает нормально.
Добавил `overflow: hidden;`, но это не помогло.

```
            <div class="slider single-item" style="overflow: hidden; padding-top:27px;" >
                <!-- Slides Container -->
                <div><a href="http://www.ololo.ru"><img class="banner"  u="image" src="/banners/Emblem_1.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div><a href="http://www.ololo.ru"><img class="banner"  u="image" src="/banners/Emblem_2.jpg" /></a></div>
                
                <div><a href="http://www.ololo.ru"><img class="banner"  u="image" src="/banners/Emblem_3.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div><a href="http://www.ololo.ru"><img class="banner"   u="image" src="/banners/Emblem_4.jpg" /></a></div>
                <div><a href="http://www.ololo.ru"><img class="banner"   u="image" src="/banners/Emblem_5.jpg" /></a></div>
                
            </div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
             var parentWidth = ((document.documentElement.clientWidth)-$(".yashare-auto-init").width())-204;
             $('.banner').css({'width':''+parentWidth+''});
             $('.slider').css({'width':''+parentWidth+''});
             $('.single-item').slick({
                 autoplay: true,
                 autoplaySpeed: 5000,
                 speed: 1000,

                 fade: true,

                 cssEase: 'linear'
                 });
            });
            
            $( window ).resize(function() {
                var parentWidth = ((document.documentElement.clientWidth)-$(".yashare-auto-init").width())-204;
            
                $('.banner').css({'width':''+parentWidth+''});
                $('.slider').css({'width':''+parentWidth+''});
             
            });
             </script>
```

Comment: скрывайте ваш слайдер до загрузки страницы, потом показывайте. Или поставьте общий загрузчик, который будет скрываться после загрузки.

Comment: Один из важных моментов который влияет на скорость загрузки в принципе - это если ваши Java Scriptы встроены в саму страницу html, если у вас таких скриптов 3-5, это уже сильно замедлит появление контента в принципе. Вам нужно вынести скрипты JS в отдельную папку все и подключить их так <script src="папка с файлом/файл.js"> </script>   И код станет чище и скорость загрузки страниц. И важное дополнение, если это возможно и картинки слайдера статичны, поменяйте их размеры на своем ПК, сделайте чтобы они весили 100-200 кб, так как если они весят по 1мб, это уже 5 мб для загрузки, что тоже влияет.

Comment: @Eric7777777 если все скрипты вынести в конец или прописать им `defer` то это не решит проблему со слайдером. Он все равно будет `мелькать` при загрузке. Лучшим вариантом здесь будет делать общий прелоадер страницы. Ну или хотя-бы `overflow: hidden; height: 0;` до загрузки и `overflow: hidden; height: auto;` после инициализации слайдера, но `но прыгать` страница все равно так будет.

Comment: Сделал пустой див с высотой слайдера. И через dispaly меняю их - один скрываю, другой показываю. Все это делаю в самом конце выполнения скрипта. Но это костыль какой-то